# Open a file without specifying the subdirectory python

Tags: python, file-io

Lets say my python script is in a folder "/main". I have a bunch of text files inside subfolders in main. I want to be able to open a file just by specifying its name, not the subdirectory its in.

So open_file('test1.csv') should open test1.csv even if its full path is /main/test/test1.csv.
I don't have duplicated file names so it should no be a problem.

I using windows.

Comment: You could make a method that adds /test in front of it, opens the file and returns its value.

Comment: @VincentBeltman, I have many subdirectories. I want it to look in all of them.

Comment: Then I can't think of a way which won't effect the performance too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

def get_file_path(file):
    for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
        if file in files:
            return os.path.join(root, file)
```

This should work. It'll return the path, so you should handle opening the file, in your code.

Answer (score 2):

you could use os.walk to find your filename in a subfolder structure

```
import os

def find_and_open(filename):
    for root_f, folders, files in os.walk('.'):
       if filename in files:
           # here you can either open the file
           # or just return the full path and process file
           # somewhere else
           with open(root_f + '/' + filename)  as f:
               f.read()
               # do something
```

if you have a very deep folder structure you might want to limit the depth of the search

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
def open_file(filename):
  f = open(os.path.join('/path/to/main/', filename))
  return f
```